# Show from jquery input feild value without storing in database

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i am new to jquery. i want to show popup div with the values entered in all fields for that i want to call by JQuery.

```
<button  id="ReviewJob">Review Your Job Posting</button>
```

When i Click the above button This popup has to appear i want to call by jQuery:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-body">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="well-sm"><span class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">Job Name </span> <span id="jobname1"></span> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Form is this:

```
<input type='text' name="jobname" id="jobname" list='Your-job' class="wp-form-control" placeholder="Name Your Job">
```

Jquery show the value entered in form

```
$("#ReviewJob").click(function() 
{
$("#myModal").modal('show');
var jobname = $("#jobname").val();
$("#jobname1").html('jobname');
});
```

Comment: what is #JobSubmit?

Comment: sorry my bad i got the solution thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Code.

Use $("#myModal").show() to Enable the Model Popup Window

```
$("#ReviewJob").click(function() 
{
  var jobname = $("#jobname").val(); // get the value of form field
  $("#jobname1").html(jobname ); // set the value to the view field
  $("#myModal").show(); // enable the model popup
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**use this**

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Comment: i cant vote your answer  i dont have 15 reputation. sorry and thank you @Akshay

Comment: it looks fine but where is your id  **"#jobname1"**

Answer (score 1):

You have called the show function wrong as per the JQuery Standards.

It should be like this.

```
$("#myModal").show();
```

While using button ensure that you give the ID for the button and then use the click function to enable the pop up for you

> jQuery Effect show() Method:

The show() method shows the hidden, selected elements.

**Note:** show() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and display:none in CSS (but not visibility:hidden).

Example:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $('#myModal').show();
    });
});
```

Please try this...

Comment: Can you please explain what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure.! i hav a form with text feild when i click review button the input value has to appear in popup.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ReviewJob").click(function(){
  $('#myModal').show();
  var jobname = $("#jobname").val();
  $("#jobname1").html(jobname);
    });
});

Your had done a small mistake., Ie while adding the variable in html field there is no need to give single quotes. now try this. you will get the result.